# how do I setText value when I on click button?

Tags: android

how do I setText value when I on click button?

now, I can get the value from my DB, but how can set text when I click the button?

```
private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer(int requestCount)  {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Load...");

        final String DATA_URL = "https://aaa.ccc/eee.php";
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        parseData(response);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }
    private void loadTravelRule() {
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer(requestCount));
        requestCount++;
    }
    
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            TravelRuleModel travelRuleModel = new TravelRuleModel();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String TAG_TravelRule = "TravelRule";
                travelRuleModel.setTravelrule(json.getString(TAG_TravelRule));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            travelRuleModels.add(travelRuleModel);
        }
    }
```

I can get json.getString(TAG_TravelRule) value, but  I want to set value in here.

```
tips.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
                View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.tips, (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer));
                travel_rule = findViewById(R.id.travel_rule);
                
                // Can I set value to R.id.travel_rule in R.layout.tips???
                if it is can set value how can I do? 

                bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
                bottomSheetDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

I tried to used

rule = json.getString(TAG_TravelRule);

then

travel_rule.setText(rule);

but I got null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the `textview` is on the `bottomSheetView` xml so you have to reference that to find your `textview`

```
travel_rule = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.travel_rule);
```